# Displaying InAppBrowser with Ionic + Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I've integrated an app with the InAppBrowser and the code works perfectly fine on Android and iOS. Now I've added the Windows platform.

I've added the shim that allows Ionic to run.

My app deploys to my device and runs.

I have a button that should open a popup InAppBrowser window. In Visual Studio, I do see WebView/1.0 showing up and the JavaScript console shows HTML1300: Navigation Ocurred and within the "File: ls" link is the HTML for the WebView.

However, on my device, the original page is displayed. The InAppBrowser WebView does not display.

Help?

Comment: Same issue here. In my application it seems like an unvisible frame that is displayed. When I click around on the page it I can get into an input element on the inappbrowser frame (the keyboard pops up) but I can't view anything. Setting hidden=no didn't help. I can get the page to load in the regular browser by setting `'_system'`

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of the added div (the ones with the `<x-ms-webview>` elements in there) has a z-index that is not high enough. if you set the z-index to 999 or something high it will become visible.

I've created a pull request [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/85).

Comment: So this works, however. What if one popup calls another? They'll both be 999 and I think the second popup will remain hidden.

Comment: You could get the zIndex of the parent div and set it one index higher?